# What does casting to `void` really do?

Tags: c++, casting, compiler-warnings, void, suppress-warnings

An often used statement like `(void)x;` allows to suppress warnings about unused variable `x`. But if I try compiling the following, I get some results I don't quite understand:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    (short)x;
    (void)x;
    (int)x;
}
```

Compiling this with g++, I get the following warnings:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -Wall -Wextra -o test
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:13: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     (short)x;
             ^
test.cpp:6:11: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     (int)x;
           ^
```

So I conclude that casting to `void` is very different from casting to any other types, be the target type the same as `decltype(x)` or something different. My guess at possible explanations is:

- It is just a convention that `(void)x;` but not the other casts will suppress warnings. All the statements equally don't have any effect.
- This difference is somehow related to the fact that `void x;` isn't a valid statement while `short x;` is.

Which of these if any is more correct? If none, then how can the difference in compiler warnings be explained?

Comment: It is just a convention amongst compilers that this cast suppresses warnings. The C++ Standard does not mention warnings for "statement has no effect" at all.

Comment: @cigien although the questions are superficially similar, this one asks about the mechanism of the difference between casts to `void` and casts to other types, while the other asks about why one would want to do the cast to `void`. However, since this question has a satisfactory answer, I won't bother to alter it and vote to reopen. This comment is just to answer the auto-generated "Does this answer your question?". TLDR: nope.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and in general, I would keep "what" and "why" questions separate. But in this case, the "what does it do" is intimately tied to the "why do it" aspect, so I think it's worth linking them. There's no reason to do this (i.e. casting to void) other than to suppress a warning, and all answers on both posts basically say the same thing.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Casting to void is used to suppress compiler warnings. The [Standard](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1054.html) says in §5.2.9/4 says,

> Any expression can be explicitly converted to type “cv void.” The
> expression value is discarded.

Comment: Could you update the link please? It doesn't go to the standard anymore, thank you

Answer (score 34):

This statement:

```
(void)x;
```

Says "Ignore the value of x."  There is no such type as `void` - it is the absence of a type.  So it's very different from this:

```
(int)x;
```

Which says "Treat x as if it were an integer."  When the resulting integer is ignored, you get a warning (if it's enabled).

When you ignore something which is nothing, it is not considered a problem by GCC--and with good reason, since casting to void is an idiomatic way to ignore a variable explicitly in C and C++.

Comment: I never thought about it like that but I am slightly confused, do you think you could give an example to clarify the concept of casting a variable to a `void`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is "such a type as `void`". See [basic.types].

Comment: @Sacert: `(void)x` is casting a variable to void.  You said it yourself.  But once you've done that, you can do nothing more with it, because a void expression has no value.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Right so I can't seem to wrap my head around why someone would want to do that? Is there ever a case where that is useful?

Comment: @Sacert: You have already identified the case where it is useful: explicitly ignoring a variable, or a return value.

Comment: It's much more useful to cast a return result to void (`(void)foo()`) to say you are deliberately ignoring the return value.  The only time I can image casting a variable to void is if the variable is only used inside some #ifdef code, and you want to suppress the warning when the code is not included.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Yes, casting a variable to void is typically done when the variable is only used in an `assert()` so would otherwise produce warnings in release builds.

Comment: From `void f()` you can return any of `(void) x`, `void(y)`, `void()` (maybe per `void(void)`?) or any `g()` that returns void itself. This way `R f(int z) { return R(z); }` covers void and nonvoid `R`.

Comment: "There is no such type as `void`". This is wrong. `void` is an incomplete type that cannot be completed. It *is* a type.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Interesting, is it the only such type? I would have asked "a type of *what*" since it's guaranteed not to describe a value, but I'm guessing it's more of a categorical distinction.

Comment: @JohnP It's an incomplete type (like what you get when you do `class Foo;` without a body). Incomplete types cannot be instantiated. But in addition, you are not allowed to define and make it complete. So, it's a special type, but it's still a type. I don't know of any other type with that property.

Answer (score 12):

The standard does not mandate generating a warning ("diagnostic" in standardese) for unused local variables or function parameters. Likewise, it does not mandate how such a warning might be suppressed. Casting a variable expression to `void` to suppress this warning has become an idiom in the C and later C++ community instead because the result cannot be used in any way (other than e.g. `(int)x`), so it's unlikely that the corresponding code is just missing. E.g.:

```
(int)x;  // maybe you meant f((int)x);
(void)x; // cannot have intended f((void)x);
(void)x; // but remote possibility: f((void*)x);
```

Personally, I find this convention too obscure still, which is why I prefer to use a function template:

```
template<typename T>
inline void ignore(const T&) {} // e.g. ignore(x);
```

The idiomatic way to ignore function parameters is, however, to omit their name (as seen above). A frequent use I have for this function is when I need to be able to name a function parameter in conditionally compiled code such as an `assert`. I find e.g. the following more legible than the use of `#ifdef NDEBUG`:

```
void rate(bool fantastic)
{
    assert(fantastic);
    ignore(fantastic);
}
```

Comment: Since C++17 you can use `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute instead of all these "creative" ways to ignore a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Possible use:

```
auto it = list_.before_begin();
for (auto& entry : list_)
{
    (void)entry; //suppress warning
    ++it;
}
```

Now the iterator 'it' points to the last element

Comment: The question was not "when is it useful", but rather "what does it do".

Comment: e.g. like mentioned in the comment: "supress warning"