# GDB - don't show result of call command

Tags: c, gdb

I have at my disposal a pretty elaborate printing function to help me debug. Unfortunately, it prints directly to a specified file stream, rather than returning a string (it returns some irrelevant value instead). `call` doesn't seem to have any parameters when I call `help call` in GDB. Is it really not possible to hide the return result of the `call` command? Or is there another command I should be entertaining?

Comment: Hm. Just a wild guess: `call (void)func(whatever)` ?

Comment: Damned good guess - it worked! Thanks! I'll post a MWE in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can cast the result of the function to `void` to discard its value.

---

## MWE

**callnoresult.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void pretty_printer() {
        fprintf(stderr, "Hello world!\n");
}

int main() {
        return 0;
}
```

Then, in terminal:

```
gcc callnoresult.c -o callnoresult
gdb ./callnoresult

<gdb message>

b main
run
call (void) pretty_printer()

<"Hello world!">
```

---

See [What does casting to `void` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288844/what-does-casting-to-void-really-do)
 for more info on the cast.