# C programming call FILE *variable

Tags: c, linux, kernel, popen

I see this code in the Linux kernel but I am not able to understand why (void) f; is being called here. Any idea?

```
    /* start 'ping' in the background to have some kfree_skb events */
    f = popen("ping -c5 localhost", "r");
    (void) f;
```

Thanks

Comment: Suppress warnings. Possible duplicate of [What does casting to \`void\` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34288844/608639)

Comment: I'm *guessing* that the variable `f` isn't used anywhere else? Then that's to suppress possible warnings about unused variables. Personally I would rather cast the call to `popen` instead of having the unused variable.

Comment: Usually `(void)f` is called to silence compiler complaints (if you don't directly reference it).

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code, as per the comment, is using `popen` to start a background process.  This function returns a `FILE *` to one end of the pipe.

This code however does not use the value of `f`.  Typically, a compiler will print a warning if a variable is unused.  Using `f` in an expression by itself casted to `void` uses the value of `f` but explicitly discards that value, preventing the warning from being printed.