# Is is valid to use a variable previously void casted?

Tags: c++, casting, void

It looks like this code is acceptable with gcc even though the standard states that the value of the expression is discarded in case of a void cast.

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int i) {
    int a = i*2;
    (void)a;
    a++; // looks OK even after void cast
    return a; // looks OK even after void cast
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "f(5): " << f(5) << "\n"; // displays 11
    return f(5);
}
```

So is it generally possible to use a change the value of a variable that has been void casted, and then what does "discarded" means in this case? Or is it a bad practice to rely on it?

Comment: I think you can examine this link for your question;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288844/what-does-casting-to-void-really-do#:~:text=Casting%20to%20void%20is%20used,The%20expression%20value%20is%20discarded.

Comment: You definitely misunderstood the standard on that part.

Comment: The value of `a`  is the result of the expression that is retrieved and then discarded. The original contents of `a`  are unaffected.

Comment: I think you're confusing the value of the variable with the variable itself. Casting has no efffect whatsoever on the cast's argument.

Comment: Not really, (1) it might call `operator int` on the object, and (2) you can cast things to `char&` and assign to it (usually causes undefined behavior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the expression is discarded, which, in your case, means that the result of `(void)a` is discarded. This is usually used to avoid unused variable (or unused return value) warnings. It is perfectly fine to use `a` after `(void)a`, but there's no point to do the `(void)a` in the first place.

EDIT: To address some concerns raised in the comments. The exact wording of the [standard](http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/c++std/cd2/expr.html) is:

> Any expression can be explicitly converted  to  type  cv  void. The
> expression  value  is discarded.

In this case `a` is the expression and it is casted to `void` which discards the result of the expression, so *"the result of (void)a"* isn't technically speaking correct: the result of `a` is discarded because it is casted to `void` - but one can also consider that the result of the cast itself is discarded (in essence, the cast does nothing).

Comment: *It means that the result of `a` is discarded.

Comment: @user202729 IMHO _"means that the result of (void)a is discarded."_ describes it better. The result of the C-style cast is discarded.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - Technically, it is both.  `(AnyType)a` has the effect of evaluating `a` and converting the result to `AnyType` (if the conversion is valid).   Putting that in a statement on its own, has the effect of discarding the result of `(AnyType)a`.    The particular case where `AnyType` is `void` has the effect of discarding `a`, and then discarding the result of discarding `a`.  <grin>  In any event, most modern compilers can detect that `(void)a` alone in a statement where `a` is an `int` has no net effect, and will most likely not emit any instructions at all, except in debug builds.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's clear. But IMHO _"The result of the expression is discarded, which, in your case, means that the result of `(void)a` is discarded."_ is a better answer than _"It means that the result of `a` is discarded."_ even though both are correct. The former better describes why `a` isn't changed. `(void)a` is a cast and the result of the cast is discarded. It doesn't change `a`. I've never said that one of the sentences is wrong.

Comment: The point of "The result of the expression is discarded, which, in your case, means that the result of (void)a is discarded." was to make things a little easier to understand. It is clear from the question that OP read the standard, so there was no point in re-iterating what the standard says, which is: "Any expression can be explicitly converted  to  type  cv  void. The expression  value  is discarded" (in this case `a` being the expression).