# Casting to void to avoid use of overloaded user-defined Comma operator

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, c++17, void

I am learning about templates in C++, and came across an example where casting to `void` is used:

```cpp
template<typename T>
auto func (T const& t) -> decltype( (void)(t.size()), T::size_type() )
{
return t.size();

}
```

In the explanation it is written that:

> The cast of the expression to void is to avoid the possibility of a user-defined comma operator overloaded for the type of the expressions.

My question(s) is/are:

1. How can a cast to void be used to "avoid the possibility of a user-defined comma operator overloaded for the type of the expressions"? I mean, can anyone give any example where if we don't use `void` then this code would give an error? For example, let's say we have a class called `SomeClass` which has overloaded the comma operator. Now, can this become a problem if we don't use `void`?
2. Can `static_cast` be used in this case instead of a C style cast? For example, something like `static_cast<void>(t.size())`. I am reading examples that use C++17 features, and so I wonder why the author has used a C style cast in this case.

I have read [What does casting to `void` really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288844/), from which I get the impression that if we use `(void)x` then this means to suppress compiler warnings, and also means "ignore the value of x". But then I can't understand the difference between the expression `x` and `(void)x`.

Comment: There's nothing stopping `T::size()` from returning an object which might have overloaded the comma operator. In which case `t.size(), T::size_type()` would be the same as `t.size().operator,(T::size_type())`

Comment: *For example lets say we have a class called SomeClass which has overloaded the comma operator. Now can this become a problem if we don't use void.* That's the example.  For class types, we don't know if `,` is regular or doing bitwise inexclusive or ;)

Answer (score 7):

Consider this pathological type:

```
struct foo {
    struct size_type {
        bool operator,(size_type) { return false;}
    };
    size_type size() { return {};}  
};
```

It does have a `size_type` and it does have a `size()` method. However, without the cast to `void`, the template does not deduce the right return type, because `decltype( (t.size()), typename T::size_type() )` is `bool` :

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
auto func (T const& t) -> decltype( (t.size()), typename T::size_type() )
{
return t.size();

}

struct foo {
    struct size_type {
        bool operator,(size_type) { return false;}
    };
    size_type size() const { return {};}  
};


int main()
{
   func(foo{});
}
```

[Results in error](https://godbolt.org/z/GW3T4W31f):

```
<source>:6:8: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'foo::size_type' to function return type 'decltype((t.size()) , typename foo::size_type())' (aka 'bool')
return t.size();
       ^~~~~~~~
<source>:20:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<foo>' requested here
   func(foo{});
   ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:6:8: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'foo::size_type' to function return type 'decltype((t.size()) , typename foo::size_type())' (aka 'bool')
return t.size();
       ^~~~~~~~
<source>:20:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func<foo>' requested here
   func(foo{});
   ^
```

A `static_cast` can be used. However, as nothing is actually being cast (it is an unevaluated context), the c-style cast does not do much harm. Note how by using the cast to `void` the user defined `operator,` is bypassed and the correct return type is deduced: https://godbolt.org/z/jozx1YGWr. This is because `void, whatever` uses the built-in `operator,` whose result is of same type as `whatever`.  You cannot override `void, whatever` with a user-defined `operator,`; there is no syntax that works.

I suppose the code is merely to illustrate this one effect, because even with the cast to `void` one can make up other examples that fail (eg the template does not explicitly test for `t.size()` actually returning `T::size_type`).

---

See also the section on "Rarely overloaded operators" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators):

> The comma operator, `operator,`. Unlike the built-in version, the overloads do not sequence their left operand before the right one. (until C++17) Because this operator may be overloaded, generic libraries use expressions such as `a,void(),b` instead of `a,b` to sequence execution of expressions of user-defined types. The boost library uses `operator,` in boost.assign, boost.spirit, and other libraries. The database access library SOCI also overloads `operator,`.

Comment: I don't get how adding(that is casting to) `void`  would remove this error. The result of the evaluation of the first expression in comma operator is discarded anyway.  Though since `decltype` is used the expression inside it will not be evaluated. How does adding `void` fix the problem. That is if we have the expression `E1, E2` then `E1` is evaluated and the result is discarded. So even if we cast `E1` to `void` its result should still be discarded. How does this help solve the overloading issue.

Comment: @JasomLiam :) I was already afraid that detail was missing. There is no custom `operator,` for void. It uses the built in one (that you already know ;). See edit

Comment: @JasonLiam It is impossible to declare a user-defined `operator,` that has a parameter of type `void`. Therefore, the only `operator,` that can be used when one of the arguments has type `void` is the built-in operator.