# Have difficulty understanding the syntax of generic lambdas for SFINAE-based traits

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, type-traits

I am reading some examples of SFINAE-based traits, but unable to make sense out of the one related to generic lambdas in C++17 ([isvalid.hpp](http://www.tmplbook.com/code/traits/isvalid.hpp.html)).

I can understand that it roughly contains some major parts in order to implement a type trait such as `isDefaultConstructible` or `hasFirst` trait ([isvalid1.cpp](http://www.tmplbook.com/code/traits/isvalid1.cpp.html)):

**1. Helper functions using SFINAE technique**:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

// helper: checking validity of f(args...) for F f and Args... args:
template<typename F, typename... Args,
         typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...))>
std::true_type isValidImpl(void*);

// fallback if helper SFINAE'd out:
template<typename F, typename... Args>
std::false_type isValidImpl(...);
```

**2. Generic lambda to determine the validity**:

```cpp
// define a lambda that takes a lambda f and returns whether calling f with args is valid
inline constexpr
auto isValid = [](auto f) {
                 return [](auto&&... args) {
                          return decltype(isValidImpl<decltype(f),
                                                      decltype(args)&&...
                                                     >(nullptr)){};
                        };
               };
```

**3. Type helper template**:

```cpp
// helper template to represent a type as a value
template<typename T>
struct TypeT {
    using Type = T;
};

// helper to wrap a type as a value
template<typename T>
constexpr auto type = TypeT<T>{};

// helper to unwrap a wrapped type in unevaluated contexts
template<typename T>
T valueT(TypeT<T>);  // no definition needed
```

**4. Finally, compose them into `isDefaultConstructible` trait to check whether a type is default constructible**:

```cpp
constexpr auto isDefaultConstructible
    = isValid([](auto x) -> decltype((void)decltype(valueT(x))()) {
        });
```

It is used like this ([Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rj4jx6Psj)):

```cpp
struct S {
    S() = delete;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "int: " << isDefaultConstructible(type<int>) << std::endl;    // true
    std::cout << "int&: " << isDefaultConstructible(type<int&>) << std::endl;  // false
    std::cout << "S: " << isDefaultConstructible(type<S>) << std::endl;        // false

    return 0;
}
```

However, some of the syntax are so complicated and I cannot figure out.

My questions are:

- With respect to 1, as for `std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args&&>()...)`, does it mean that it is an `F` type functor taking `Args` type constructor? And why it uses forwarding reference `Args&&` instead of simply `Args`?
- With respect to 2, as for `decltype(isValidImpl<decltype(f), decltype(args)&&...>(nullptr)){}` , I also cannot understand why it passes forwarding reference `decltype(args)&&` instead of simply `decltype(args)`?
- With respect to 4, as for `decltype((void)decltype(valueT(x))())`, what is the purpose of `(void)` casting here? (`(void)` casting can also be found in [isvalid1.cpp](http://www.tmplbook.com/code/traits/isvalid1.cpp.html) for `hasFirst` trait) All I can find about `void` casting is [Casting to void to avoid use of overloaded user-defined Comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314599/casting-to-void-to-avoid-use-of-overloaded-user-defined-comma-operator), but it seems it is not the case here.

Thanks for any insights.

---

P.S. For one who wants more detail could check [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide, 2nd](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714121) - *19.4.3 Using Generic Lambdas for SFINAE*. The author also mentioned that some of the techniques are used widely in [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html), so I also listen to [Louis Dionne's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cg1wOINjV9U) about it. Yet, it only helps me a little to understand the code snippet above. (It is still a great talk about the evolution of C++ metaprogramming)

Comment: try to focus on one question. Sometimes it takes more than one question to tackle a bigger thing.

Comment: A reason for casting to `void` here is that you really don't want the type, just know if there *is* a type. And if you have bad luck, it could be a type that *exists*, but cannot be returned by a function.

Comment: One question per post. Someone might know answer to some part of your question but not to other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. F is a function object callable with Args...
   For the sake of mental model, picture `std::declval<F>()` as a "fully constructed object of type F". `std::declval` is there just in case F is not default-constructible and still needs to be used in unevaluated contexts.
   For a default-constructible type this would be equivalent:
   `F()(std::declval<Args&&>()...);` In essence it's a call to F's constructor and then call to its `operator()` with forwarded `Args`. But imagine one type is constructible with int, another one is default-constructible, yet another one requires a string. Without some unevaluated constructor-like metafunction it would be impossible to cover all those cases.
   You can read more on that in Alexandrescu's *Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied*.
2. Adding `&&` to the argument type is effectively perfect-forwarding it. It may look obscure, but it's just a shorthand for `decltype(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args))`. See the [implementation of `std::forward`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward) and [reference collapsing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725747/concise-explanation-of-reference-collapsing-rules-requested-1-a-a-2) for more details. Keep in mind though, that this snippet adds rvalue-reference that collapses to the correct one when combined with the original type, not a forwarding one.
3. As it was stated in the comments: the type is not really needed, possibilty exists it cannot be returned, its presence there is just to check expression's correctness, afterwards it can be discarded.

Comment: For 1., I try to replace `std::declval<F>()` with simply `F()`, but the now the output would be incorrect for int type even it is constructible: ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/59o8bW63o)). 
I cannot fully understand the reason for this. Is this also because of the necessity of unevaluated context?

Comment: Notice that a lambda is passed to `isValid` and that its type is then passed to `isValidImpl` as a template argument, and lambdas are not default constructible, therefore you're hitting the "sink-everything" function. Comment out the sink and it becomes clear https://godbolt.org/z/vETnjcxvr